# Azure Sql Database/Synapse Dedicated Pool create a sa user

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

We are migrating some servers across regions, not easy for a Synapse Workspace. We have a working solution in several steps but the last thing is to copy the logins (with the passwords).

We have found some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances) that shows how you can script this.

On Server A in the `aster` database from the Synapse Workspace we can login with the sqladmin user assigned in the portal, that user is able to execute that script that creates the stored procedures.

But the sqladmin user is not granted execute permission, so we can't find a way to grant execution permission to (another/the) user that could execute the script.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That procedure, is old, bugging, and actually can suffer from injection. You are likely better off *not* using it. Especially as It was written well ebfore AZure SQL Database, or Azure SQL Datawarehouse existed.

Comment: Side note, you've tagged [[tag:azure-sql-database]] and [[tag:azure-sqldw]] here, but your question talks about Synapse; should you actually be tagging [[tag:azure-synapse]]?

Comment: Wel, this is not realy Synapse, it is the Sql-Partg of synapse that is causing me some troubles.

Comment: @Larnu, any suggestion on how to do better, cause the genberate scripts from SSMS fails if I include the logins.